# Is it possible to create a set of pointers to objects in cpp?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, set

While trying to create a cpp set of objects, I came across this question

[How do i insert objects into STL set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871647/how-do-i-insert-objects-into-stl-set)
 But my doubt is that, is there any way to not store actual objects in the set but pointers to them and still be able to maintain the unique entity property of the set.

Comment: [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) allows you to specify a custom comparator. In your case, you can either create a wrapper type for your pointers that does deep object comparison, or use plain pointers with a custom comparator, where the comparator dereferences the pointer and compares the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) template is parameterised as

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

To store **pointers** to a type `T`, yet ensure that the **values** are *unique* you simply need to provide an appropriate `Compare` functor that can compare pointers by comparing their dereferenced values.

For example, for pointers to `some_type` we could use something like:

```
class comparison {
   bool operator()(const some_type* lhs, const some_type* rhs) const {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

and then declare the set as

```
std::set<some_type*, comparison> s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom comparator in std::set to de-reference the object and compare.

```
bool compare_int(const int*& l, const int*& r) {
    return (*l) < (*r);
}
std::set<int*, compare_int> intSet;

int   myInt     = 5;
int*  myIntPtr  = &myInt;

inSet.insert(myIntPtr);
```