# Why is operator< overloading necessary for STL set containing custom objects, instead of operator==

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

I'm working with C++11 and I want to use `set` to store my custom objects because I need a container, which can filter the elements with the same value.

Here is the class of my custom object:

```
struct Ele
{
    int a, b, c;
}
```

As my understanding, I need to overload the function `operator==` because `set` need to filter the elements with the same value.

However, after reading this link: [How do i insert objects into STL set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871647/how-do-i-insert-objects-into-stl-set), it seems that overloading `operator<` is what I need, instead of `operator==`.

So I code like this:

```
struct Ele {
    int a, b, c;
    friend bool operator<(const Ele &e1, const Ele &e2);
};
bool operator<(const Ele &e1, const Ele &e2)
{
    if (e1.a < e2.a) {
        return true;
    }
    if (e1.a == e2.a) {
        if (e1.b < e2.b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (e1.b == e2.b) {
            if (e1.c < e2.c) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And do a test as below:

```
set<Ele> myset;
Ele e1;
e1.a = 1;
e1.b = 2;
e1.c = 3;
Ele e2;
e2.a = 1;
e2.b = 2;
e2.c = 3;
myset.insert(e1);
myset.insert(e2);
cout << myset.size() << endl;
```

Well, the output is `1`, instead of `2`, which means that the insertion for `e2` failed as expected because the value of `e2` is the same with the value of `e1`.

Now I'm confused.

As my understanding, `operator<` just told the compiler how to understand `e1 < e2`, how does compiler know how to understand `e1 == e2`? What if I want to set such a rule: `e1 == e2` only if `e1.a == e2.b && e1.b == e2.c && e1.c == e2.a`?

Comment: [Some reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), specifically *strict weak ordering* and how is `equiv` defined.

Comment: Because `std::set` is an *ordered* container, which needs to know a relative ordering between elements, not only if two elements are equal? (Note that `<` can be used to check for equality as well.)

Comment: We just got C++20, where we'll have `operator<=>`. That can do all comparisons.

Comment: If you had that `operator ==` then it wouldn't be valid for standard containers, because standard containers expect that if A==B then B==A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` is not sufficient on its own to define an ordering, whereas `<` is. Furthermore all other relational operators can be cast in terms of `operator<`, so long as you are allowed to negate the result.

For example, `a == b` if `!(a < b)` and `!(b < a)`

`<` is a natural choice insofar that thinking of things being in ascending order is natural. `>` could have been picked, but it wouldn't have been so tractable.

Comment: Any one of `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=` plus `!` can be used to synthesize an order, but `<` is the "most" natural for ascending order. `>` is natural for descending order

Answer (score 1):

`operator<` is required because `std::map` internally is implicitly required by the standard to be a tree-like data structure that requires some kind ordering between elements. Notice that one can generate all the comparing functions using just `operator<`. Take a look:

```
a == b <==> !(a < b) && !(b < a)
a > b <==> b < a
a >= b <==> !(a < b)
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

You *could* ensure uniqueness with `==` (and `!`), but it would be less efficient than using `<` (`std::set`) or a hash function (`std::unordered_set`).

Consider insert. With only `==` you would have to compare every element to verify that you don't have an equal element already. `std::set`'s elements are kept in order, so insert does a binary search, looking at far fewer elements. `std::unordered_set`'s elements are kept in buckets based on the hash value, so lookup only has to search the bucket, not the whole collection.

As noted in [Bathsheba's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791516/2610810) answer, you can synthesize an equality function from `<`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already point out that `std::set` requires an *ordering* of the elements which requires `operator<` to be defined for the type. If you don't care about ordering, and only care about uniqueness, you can use `std::unordered_set`.

Also, here's a much cleaner way to implement the comparison:

```
bool operator<(const Ele &e1, const Ele &e2)
{
  return std::tie(e1.a, e1.b, e1.c) < std::tie(e2.a, e2.b, e2.c);
}
```